# Reactjs website Images working in internet explorer but not chrome or firefox?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, webpack

I can import images using `import img from './imagesource'` & `image src={img}` in my Reactjs component and it will work just fine in internet explorer. However firefox and chrome will not show the images.

I have tried moving the file containing the images into the public folder and `image src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'filename'}`, I have tried changing url-loader limit in webpack-config. I checked the path with dev tools and they are the same in both browsers and no matter what image I replace it with the result is the same.

//Importing and html

```
import Image from '../Images/profpic.JPG';

image src={Image} className={classes.picture}
```

//webpack url-loader

```
     {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
```

//webpack file-loader

```
      {
        exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
```

Not sure what is going on. Initially I thought it was a path problem but the paths seem to be the same on all browsers.[firefox inspect elemtent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQoif.jpg)
[internet explorer inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eopqz.jpg)

Comment: Inspect the element in internet explorer, and chrome, and post the differences looking at the devtools. The network tab may also give you some information as to why it is not loading.

Comment: Added pics of inspect element on both firefox and internet explorer. I can put the site up on a server if that would help anyone wanting to inspect?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Apparently chrome and firefox will not recognize `<img>`,  `<image />`, or `<image></image>`. I used `<img />` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your file extension of the file to JPG to jpg (make sure you change it on the image file itself as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring the Image file, as of:

```
const image = require("../Images/profpic.JPG");
```

or

```
<img src={require("../Images/profpic.JPG")} />
```

and try renaming the extension to lowercase

Comment: I have tried requiring and using just about every file extension. I've also checked with a few other computers so it's not just my browser settings.